# Javascript error; Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I keep getting this error **(Javascript error; Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list)** when trying to call a simple function. Everything works without calling it in a function but I need to do it multiple times.

```
function myFunction(ip, port, div) {
    $.get('http://mcping.net/api/'+ ip + ":" + port, function(data){
        console.log(data.online);
        $(div).html(data.online);
    });
}
myFunction(162.223.8.210, 25567, #factionsOnline)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing a parentheses because you didn't quote your strings

```
myFunction('162.223.8.210', '25567', '#factionsOnline');
```

Comment: oh, thought because they were numbers, they wouldn't need it?

Comment: The numbers stricly don't but you're joining them with strings anyway, but the last argument isn't a number

Comment: Also `162.223.8.210` is not a valid number, so that needs to be quoted

Comment: alright, thanks. Also what is better to use single quotes or double quotes?